# Spring Boot @Autowired trouble in Spring Guide

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-pubsub

It is an error & exception in the application on messagingGateway(WebAppController): ***Could not autowire. No beans of 'PubsubOutboundGateway' type found.***
Interface PubsubOutboundGateway was imported proper, don't understand that is the issue source.

WebAppController:

```
@RestController
public class WebAppController {
    @Autowired
    private PubsubOutboundGateway messagingGateway;
}
```

PubSubApplication:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
public interface PubsubOutboundGateway {

    void sendToPubsub(String text);
}
```

The code is from offical Spring Boot examples repository: [spring-guides
/gs-messaging-gcp-pubsub](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-messaging-gcp-pubsub/tree/master/complete/src/main/java/hello)

How could I make it working?

Comment: Can you share more code. For example the PubSubApplication with the class and the annotation on it? Can you share your dependency file (Maven or Gradle)?

Comment: Did you try to use @ComponentScan() on your main Methode? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning